# Can "A and B" be followed by "is"?

Tags: grammar, verb-usage

This is an excerpt from an ESL reading book. What I want to ask is whether "Their independence and ability" can be regarded as a single concept, so "is" can be followed.

> The number of working women has been steadily increasing in recent
>   years. Most significantly, many mothers with young children have been
>   returning to work rather than staying at home. Furthermore, the “glass
>   ceiling” that for so long has kept women from being promoted to
>   executive positions seems to have been shattered. These women, who are
>   able to balance their roles as both mothers and corporate executives,
>   are being referred to as “alpha moms.” Their independence and ability
>   **is** quickly erasing past stereotypes that portrayed working mothers as overworked and exhausted.

Comment: It should be are; there is a compound subject.

Answer (score 1):

Their independence and their ability may be working together, but they don't really seem like a single cohesive item. In this case, you should use "are" so that the verb agrees with the compound subject.

If you really want to use a singular verb to emphasize that the two are working together, then you could revise the sentence to use a singular subject, such as:

> The combination of their independence and ability is quickly erasing past stereotypes...